# How to get access localStorage inside asyncData in Nuxt js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I tried accessing localStorage inside asyncData but the result is "localStorage is not defined"

```
asyncData(){
     if(localStorage.getItem("myCat")){
        alert(localStorage.getItem("myCat"));
        return;
      }
     
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localStorage` is not defined because `asyncData()` is resolved on the server during SSR. The `localStorage` variable is only accessible in the client browser.

See documentation: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching/. You can use localStorage in the `mounted()` hook.

Comment: You can't use `localStorage` in `created()` hook yet

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Jakub Záruba's answer, if you need to access `localStorage` in `asyncData` nonetheless, you can modify your `if`-statement like this:

```js
if (process.client && localStorage.getItem("myCat")) {
  alert(localStorage.getItem("myCat"))
  
  return
}
```

so you will run this piece of code only on the client-side.